# Double dotted border while using colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have what seems like a simple problem, but searching the net hasn't yielded any results.

I have a table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="something.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Hello
        </td>
        <td>
            World
        </td>
        <td>
            !
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `<tr>` elements all have `border-top: dotted 1px black`, this works fine apart from the central `<td>` element in the second `<tr>`.

This element has a double border and so appears as a solid line, removing the `colspan` fixes the issue.

I have tried applying `border-collapse: collapse` to the the table and this hasn't worked, I have tried adding content in the form of `&nbsp;` inside the first `<td>` instead of an image and this hasn't worked either.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: is the table also has border? try with setting table border as none.

Comment: The `<table>` has no border and the `<td>`s have no borders.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you seeing this in?  I'm not getting it in a jsfiddle running Firefox 7.0.1: http://jsfiddle.net/yePHg/

Comment: Chrome 14.0, just tried in Firefox 7.0.1 and it works fine for me. Both on Mac OS X.

Comment: Can you please post the full CSS / HTML you are using for this rather than just the snippet?

Comment: I would, but it's got a huge style sheet, it's also in a logged in area of a site. This is the best I can provide.

Comment: 2019 and this is still an issue.  not sure if it's a bug in chrome but sure seems like one

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Adding `border-collapse: separate;` to your table fixes the issue, see **[http://jsfiddle.net/quyMy/](http://jsfiddle.net/quyMy/1/)**

I've added a dynamic test case to that fiddle. Click anywhere, and the visibility of the original/new table will toggle, allowing you to see the difference much easier.

Another way to get rid off the unexpected border is to add a plain `<tr></tr>` after the row containing `<td colspan=3>`.

Comment: No solid answer yet still Rob W. So, you win!

Answer (score 3):

If you set the border on the table cells instead of the table rows, it will work.

I could only reproduce the bug in IE, but there are other known issues with the way that tables in IE render borders.

See this:  http://jsfiddle.net/yePHg/19/

Comment: Thanks Victor, I am sure i have tried this though. I will try again.

Answer (score 2):

Add a row with a <hr /> between and then give the border to that hr

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Gec/

Comment: upvoted for out of the box respectable fix. Interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying css `display: block;` on the tr:

```
    tr
    {
        border-top: 1px dotted #000;
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css:

```
<style>
table, table * { border:0; padding:0; margin:0 }
table td { border-top:1px dotted #000 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same problem!

```
border-collapse: separate
```

worked great, but it also separated my borders (shocker, right?). I wanted a single dotted line. So here's what I did.

CSS:

```
td {
border-right: 1px dotted #bbb;
border-left: 1px dotted #bbb;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #bbb;
border-top: none;
padding: .5em;
}

th {
border-right: 1px dotted #bbb;
border-left: 1px dotted #bbb;
border-top: 1px dotted #bbb;
border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
padding: .5em;
}
```

HTML

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5"> DRESSES &amp; TOPS </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> size </td>
        <td> numerical </td>
        <td> bust </td>
        <td> waist </td>
        <td> hip< </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```