# Dotted border on table cells turns solid

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I've set up a [jsfiddle][1] with my test case.

Basically, I have a table with a dotted border on the bottom of some cells and a solid border on others. For some reason, the dotted borders are turning to solid ones on some cells, I can't figure out why. Could anybody explain this behaviour and/or provide a fix for it?

I'm using Chrome.

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/eZcSR/1/

Comment: Exactly where the dooted turns to solid? - http://jsfiddle.net/eZcSR/27/

Comment: on my version it would have been Row-1 Cell-2 and Row-1 Cell-4 but in yours they are not - but it doesn't look like you changed anything apart from the text? why does it happen in my version then?

Comment: which OS you have? DOes it happend only in Chrome?

Comment: I'm on windows 7, works as expected in FF and IE - so just chrome by the looks ok it

Comment: Your CSS is now missing from jsfiddle. I played with it a bunch and I see the issue in Chrome on OS X. I think it may be a browser issue. I did notice if you switch to CSS tables the issue goes away. I was going to check it in Chrome on Windows but now your CSS is missing...

Comment: my CSS is still there, click the original link

Comment: this may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941640/css-dotted-border-issue-in-adjacent-columns-in-a-table-rendered-as-dash-in-chrom ?

Comment: Strange, your CSS was gone when I checked it in ~5 browsers on two machines. This issue also only occurs with dotted - eg not dashed. When I resize the browser window, the area that's solid can change. I think @TimRodham is right with his suggestion on a related issue.

Comment: the problem seems to be reliant on the colspan attribute of the cells underneath - and not upon the other solid bordered cells

Comment: btw - the CSS is probably gone because you are on the wrong version? try version 1 as in the original link

Answer (score -1):

Adding

`border-collapse: separate;`

Or adding `border-spacing: 0`

Or adding an empty `<tr></tr>` to the row above (??!)

Fixes the issue as in this question: [Double dotted border while using colspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725110/double-dotted-border-while-using-colspan)